# How to Choose Error Distribution For Time-Series Model

Tags: time-series, distributions, forecasting, model-selection

I am modelling a set of time-series, and understand various models (ARIMA, AR, GARCH) allow for the inclusion of non-Gaussian error distributions. I am aware that, after fitting a time-series model, we should perform residual analysis, checking for no correlation, mean 0 and so on.

I was wondering if, given a time-series, there was anything that suggests what error distribution to use before fitting a model? As far as I am aware, simply looking at the distribution of the time-series values is not applicable, as we are modelling errors, not the series it's self.

Packages such as `rugarch` offer a range of error distributions - Gaussian, t, skewed-t, normal inverse Gaussian and so on, but is there any way to know which of these might best suit a data-set, without trying each of them and checking what works best?

Comment: the truth is everybody just goes with Gaussian and doesn't bother. you could try Student t, but it's just more work for really no benefit, plus it may land you in trouble if you're dealing with log variables. you could also go non-parametric, i.e. not assume any distribution, e.g. time series regression such as AR(1) are easy to do this way